# get_users is missing or skipping over users in loop

Tags: wp-query

I want to paginate through all users in a WP site in groups of 100. The code below is a simplified version:

```
for($offset = 0; $offset < 100; $offset++)

    $args = ["number" => 100, 'orderby' => 'ID'];

    $args['offset'] = ($offset - 1) * (int) $args['number'];

    $users = get_users($args);
    
    //Do Stuff with $users
   
}
```

The issue is that I seem to be skipping over some Users. I've logged the User IDs from the loop and checked them against the Users section in the dashboard, I can find User IDs that don't appear in the logs but do appear in Users.

I'm aware there is also a 'paged' parameter but I got the same result when using it.

Anyone seen anything like this before?

Comment: is this a complete example that you've confirmed reproduces your issue by testing?

Comment: The code above is a simplified loop from a more complex block. Ultimately when we 'do stuff' with the $user array, we're finding there are User IDs missing. In other words, get_users seems to be skipping over User IDs or otherwise not returning them.

Comment: And why is 1 subtracted from `$offset`?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is a basic PHP problem. You're only looping over the even numbers, 0, 2, 4, 6

This is because at the end of every loop `$offset` increases by 1:

```php
for($offset = 0; $offset < 100; $offset++)
```

But then for some reason it also gets incremented before the loop ends:

```php
$offset++;
```

So offset is incremented by 2, and half the values are skipped

Comment: Sorry, when I simplified the code I forgot to remove the ending increment. I've updated the code to reflect this.

Comment: There should not be an ending increment, you may have fixed your problem by simplifying it

Comment: The code in the question has been corrected. When I simplified the block, I forgot to remove it. Unfortunately, it renders this answer incorrect as it was based, entirely my fault, on incorrect code.

Comment: I'm giving Tom's answer an upvote because it correctly identifies the problem with your code (the double increment)....no judgement, we all make simple errors from time to time and an extra pair of eyes on it is really helpful, but it's only fair to Tom that his spotting skills are recognized.

Answer (score 0):

We ran this code a number of times and we were unable to narrow it down. We hypothesize that it is being caused by some custom caching or SQL limiting mechanism in the hosting company as the User table is quite large (14k records) Or, alternatively, another plugin is hooking the get_user /DB query.

We eventually wrote a raw query that is based on the User ID:

```
$users = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->users WHERE ID > $maxUserId ORDER BY ID ASC LIMIT 50");
```

Where $maxUserId is a variable we store after each run which stores the highest User ID seen in a given result set. Therefore, on each run, we get the next batch of user IDs which is effectively pagination.

It's not a good solution but it's the only one we found, for this given use case, that would guarantee us seeing each and every User ID in the database.